# finding distance between 2 coordinates in google map in android

Tags: android

I am developing a google map application.I have called map activity class.On the google map I have showed the current location as well as multiple markers.Now the problem i am facing is to calculate distance between 2 coordinates having there respective value....Has anyone implemented it before??It will be a great help for me.....Thanks in advance

Comment: 22 questions with 0% accepted answers? You need to work on being a better member of this community. Please. That's how SO works and prospers and how we prosper from it. You should also work on the quality of your questions. I checked some of your past posts and they seem to be lacking in detail just as this one and more. Try Google first and make an attempt. You'll be surprised how much more effective you'll find SO if you do those things.

Comment: Please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: And no, you have not provided sufficient detail. In this question or in previous ones. It is quite obvious that you're making little effort in researching any solution before asking VERY high-level questions here.

Comment: After the map activity is called,Then i have to paste this code??

Comment: The code you have mentioned here.I have applied that in the class.When i run the code.Only map shows.Nothing else than that,,,,,

Answer (score 3):

For example, [look what turned up as the very first Google result](http://advback.com/android/finding-distance-between-two-points-with-google-maps-android/) when I searched for ["android calculate map distance between points"](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1SNNT_enUS377US377&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=android+calculate+map+distance+between+points)

Code snippet:

```
double distance;  

Location locationA = new Location("point A");  

locationA.setLatitude(latA);  
locationA.setLongitude(lngA);  

Location locationB = new Location("point B");  

locationB.setLatitude(latB);  
LocationB.setLongitude(lngB);  

distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
```

Comment: its not giving driving distance